# SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word on running mocha with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

On running the enzyme test by using mocha. I am getting the error

> (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React fro
>                                                                 ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

I have the below-given test script in my test file

```
import React from 'react';
import { assert } from 'chai';
import { render } from 'enzyme';
import Book from '../src/Book';

describe("Book", () => {
it("render text", () => {
const wrapper = render(<Book author="Dan Abramov" title="Redux and ReactJS" />);

assert.equal(wrapper.text(), 'Redux and ReactJS by Dan Abramov');
});
});
```

I have tried to replace **import** with **require**, did not work. It would be wonderful if someone give a helping hand to figure out the issue.

**EDIT**
I am including the package.json file below,

```
{
"name": "test-client",
"version": "0.0.1",
"description": "test companies client.",
"repository": "https://github.com/Test/test-client",
"main": "js/app.js",
"directories": {
"test": "test"
},
"scripts": {
"test": "mocha"
},

"dependencies": {
"classnames": "2.2.*",
"clone": "^1.0.2",
"es5-shim": "4.1.*",
"es6-object-assign": "1.0.*",
"es6-promise": "3.0.*",
"flux": "^2.1.1",
"font-awesome": "^4.5.0",
"form-data": "^1.0.0-rc3",
"hashids": "^1.0.2",
"howler": "^1.1.29",
"isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
"js-cookie": "^2.1.0",
"json3": "3.3.*",
"keymirror": "0.1.*",
"normalize.css": "^4.0.0",
"react": "^15.0.1",
"react-addons-create-fragment": "^15.0.1",
"react-dnd": "^2.1.4",
"react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.1.2",
"react-dom": "^15.0.1",
"react-infinite": "^0.9.2",
"react-paginate": "^1.0.4",
"react-tooltip": "^2.0.0",
"socket.io-client": "1.3.*",
"twemoji": "^2.0.5",
"unorm": "^1.4.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"browserify": "^6.2.0",
"catw": "^1.0.1",
"dockerode": "^2.0.4",
"dotenv": "^2.0.0",
"envify": "^3.4.0",
"gulp-awspublish": "^3.0.2",
"less": "^2.6.1",
"reactify": "^0.15.2",
"watchify": "^3.4.0"
},
"browserify": {
"transform": [
  "reactify",
  "envify"
]
},
"scripts": {
"start-css": "catw -c 'lessc -' 'css/src/*.less' -o css/bundle.css -v",
"start-js": "watchify -o js/bundle.js -v -d js/app.js",
"start": "npm run start-css & npm run start-js"
},
"author": "Test"
}
```

Comment: Do you already have a setup where you can run ES2015 code?

Comment: Do you have the .babelrc? mocha is automatically include this for setting the env es2015

Comment: @robertklep No. But I have tried this http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/installation/react-15.html

Comment: @MichaelRasoahaingo I have done nothing apart from the mocha setup. I will update the question with my package.json file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your test uses ES2015, for which you require a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

To get this working with Mocha, you first need to install a few packages:

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react
```

Next, add the following to your `package.json`:

```
"babel": {
  "presets": [ "es2015", "react" ]
}
```

Or, if you don't have a `package.json`, create a file called `.babelrc` in the working directory, containing the following:

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015", "react" ]
}
```

Lastly, tell Mocha to use the Babel transpiler:

```
$ mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register test.js
```

Comment: Even after that I am getting the same error response.

Comment: And after the installation the package.json file automatically updated with the following script   **"babel-cli": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",**

Comment: @muneermuhammed it's expected that `package.json` gets updated, because of the `--save-dev` option. Still, with these instructions it _should_ work (it does for me). Which version of Node are you using?

Comment: The node version is **v0.10.33**

Comment: @muneermuhammed I would seriously suggest upgrading, I'm guessing that 0.10 is just too old.

Comment: Really. Then I will upgrade and give it another shot.

Comment: I have updated the version to **v6.2.1**. And no change yet.

Comment: Did you put the Babel configuration in `package.json` or in `.babelrc`?

Comment: I have updated the packge.json with the Babel configuration.

Comment: And for the last command **mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register test.js** the respone is **bash: mocha: command not found**.

Comment: Yes, it is working right now. Thanks @robertklep. I have replaced the **""test": "mocha"**  script  with **"test": "mocha test/.setup.js test/test.js"**

Comment: @roverklep What should I do to change es2015 to es5 ? When I manually changed this getting error.

Comment: @muneermuhammed ES5 is what Node currently runs, so you would either need to transpile all ES2015 code to ES5 (which is basically what Babel is already doing for you), or you need to rewrite your code to ES5.

Comment: Thank you so much, it saved so much time.