# Unexpected reserved word 'import' react into nodejs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Installed and imported react and react router packages at the start of app js file but get this error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React from 'react';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

In my app.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

var express = require('express'),
...
```

Comment: `import` statements can only occur at the top level scope. You can't import inside a function.

Comment: @jared I imported at the top of my file, didn't import in a function

Comment: *in the code you posted with the error* it shows an import statement *inside a wrapper function* that was likely applied by a code transformer. Its the *code that runs* that matters, not what you wrote originally.

Answer (score 0):

Your you are ES2015 and you require a transpiler like Babel.

To get this working, you first need to install a few packages:

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react
```

Next, add the following to your package.json:

```
"babel": {
  "presets": [ "es2015", "react" ]
}
```

Or, if you don't have a package.json, create a file called .babelrc in the working directory, containing the following:

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015", "react" ]
}
```

**Note**

It is not an exact duplicate but it had the same answer as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679590/syntaxerror-unexpected-reserved-word-on-running-mocha-with-enzyme) post. Thanks to "robertklep" for the answer.

**UPDATE**

If you are using Webpack, make sure you are loading babel via module loader.

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
        },
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      },
}
```

Comment: I did install babel and all the other packages but it's still not working :/ And I added the codes above

Comment: Are you using Webpack?

Comment: Yes, using webpack. But I haven't generated a bundle js file yet. Also added  "babel": "babel", "webpack": "webpack" to scripts in package.json

Comment: I'm also using an online IDE (cloud9) to run this.

Comment: @Jon you should load babel module if didn't. I updated my answer. I hope it solves the issue.

Comment: @Jon did you try it?

Comment: Still not working... I'm using express too, should I require react instead of import? Like installing packages like this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-react-router-views)

Comment: It is because babel is not transpiling your code. Did you try creating ".babelrc" file how I described it????

Comment: @Jon import should work if you add your webpack config it will be easier to find out why it is not working. But if it is taking time and you want to prevent time wasting, why not, go on and use require it should solve.